# Accessing and Querying Event Log in Windows

Tags: c#, arrays, event-log

I was wondering how I could reach event Log entries. I have a client server application and it executes without problems. What i am looking for is all instances of log with the id of 1149. This log is of the remote connection entries. I have taken a piece of code, here it is.

```
string logType = "System";
string str = "";
EventLog ev = new EventLog(logType, System.Environment.MachineName);
int LastLogToShow = ev.Entries.Count;
if (LastLogToShow <= 0)
    Console.WriteLine("No Event Logs in the Log :" + logType);

// Read the last 2 records in the specified log. 
int i;
for (i = ev.Entries.Count; i >= LastLogToShow - 1000 ; i--)
{
    EventLogEntry CurrentEntry = ev.Entries[i];
    if (CurrentEntry.InstanceId == 1149)
    {
        str += "Event type: " + CurrentEntry.EntryType.ToString() + "\n" +
               "Event Message: " + CurrentEntry.Message + CurrentEntry + "\n" +
               "Event Time: " + CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString() + "\n" +
               "Event : " + CurrentEntry.UserName +"\n" +"\n";
    }
}
ev.Close();
return str;
```

The thing is I get the 42567 index is out of bounds exception everytime. I also dont know if it will work after that, so questions may follow.

EDIT:
Indeed, the problem was me reaching out of the eventlog with my index like you guys said. Using this line for the loop solved my problem here and I am able to reach the eventlog now, if anyone is looking around, this solution worked for me, so thank you all so much.

```
for (i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This `for (i = ev.Entries.Count; i >= LastLogToShow - 1000 ; i--)` is causing your error. I don't really get what you're trying to do here. For one if you have less than 1000 entries, your `i` can be negative. When you use a negative value as the index of an array you will get "index is out of bounds exception". When you are trying to process only the last 2 records (as your commentary above the for-loop suggests) you should just use this:

```
for (i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= ev.Entries.Count - 2; i--)
```

Of course you will still have to check if there is more than 2 entries because if there are 0 entries, the code will still go into the for-loop and try to access the array with negative indexes:

```
if(ev.Entries.Count < 2)
  return str;
for (i = ev.Entries.Count - 1; i >= ev.Entries.Count - 2; i--)
```

**Edit:** Also just noticed even if there are more than 1000 records, when you go into the for-loop for the first time you will have `ev.Entries[ev.Entries.Count]`. Since array-indexes are zero-based you have to substract 1 from the count to get the last element of an array.

Answer (score 2):

I highly suggest you use C# Linq for this.

Add this namespace

```
using System.Linq;
```

Linq is very similar to SQL in how it works with the data. In your case:

```
List<string> stringLogs = 
    ev.Entries
        .Where(t => t.InstanceId == 1149)
        .Select(t => GenerateLogString(t))
        .ToList();

public string GenerateLogString(EventLogEntry CurrentEntry)
{
    return
        string.Format("Event type: {0}\nEvent Message: {1}\nEvent Time: {2}\nEvent: {3}\n",
            CurrentEntry.EntryType.ToString(),
            CurrentEntry.Message + CurrentEntry,
            CurrentEntry.TimeGenerated.ToShortTimeString(),
            CurrentEntry.UserName)
}
```

You can then convert the string logs into a single string, like you have there.

```
string str = string.Join("/n", stringLogs);
```

If you want to select the top 2 logs (as your commentary suggests), add a .Take(2) to the query, like below.

```
List<string> stringLogs = 
    ev.Entries
        .Where(t => t.InstanceId == 1149)
        .Take(2)
        .Select(t => GenerateLogString(t))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you, will use LINQ, once I have tested the program thoroughly, it's better performance wise right?

Comment: Definitely, much better performance, and a much safer implementation. Please update correct answer if you do use my implemention. :) This method will also work regardless of how many elements you have. As you are never requesting an element using an index, OutOfRange exceptions are not possible.

Comment: Although in your case it is not as big a concern, LINQ is incredible when working with very large datasets as you can do [deferred execution](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-nz/library/bb943859.aspx) to prevent any massive loads on your application. Ping me if you need help. :)

Answer (score 1):

You just need to equal i to ev.Entries.Count -1.
i = (ev.Entries.Count -1)